# Theme.Dialog - style 4.3 to look like 2.3?

Tags: android, dialog, themes

I designed my app on a 2.3 device and was really happy with the Theme.Dialog I used for my activities to open them floating above the main activity.

However, when moving to 4.3 I don't like the look of the dialogs - the background is darker and not semi-transparent as before and they lack the white rounded border.

How can I use the old theme or change the default theme to look like 2.3?  If I found the source code could I use that to create my own theme?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

Perhaps my question wasn't clear enough.  I would like my activity dialogs to always look like this image (2.3 style), no matter what version of the OS or manufacturer.  How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: you do realize that if you haven't customized the dialog yourself, the dialog is shown according to what the OS has as default (customized by manufacturers) , right? if you wish to change it, do something like what was made on HoloEverywhere library.

Comment: I've updated my question. I would like to customise it myself to always look like the above image

Comment: i think you should avoid such a thing, since it's exactly the same as old android versions, and it can confuse end users to see it while everything on the OS is much more native. another reason is that the buttons on alert dialogs have changed their order, so the OK button is now on the right and not on the left. example here: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/confirming-acknowledging.html

Answer (score 1):

Create style file with a custom theme:

`values/styles.xml`

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
</style>
```

... and assign this theme to your activity in android manifest

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity
    android:name="<your activity class name here>"
    android:theme="@style/DialogTheme" />
```

Comment: thanks but I would like to style the dialog to always look like the 2.3 version - i've updated my question